# Can an Android App lose its components weightings?

Tags: android

I have an android app that consists (in landscape mode) in a vertical sense:
an action bar
an imageview
a seek bar
and another linear layout, having buttons on it.

The weightings of the imageview, seekbar and the button bar are 0.8, 0.1 and 0.1
respectively.
When I activate one of the buttons to load an image into the imageview, and after the file chooser dialog is closed and the image is displayed, the weightings of the seekbar and the control bar are no longer the same. They seem to be about 0.07 each, and as a result there is a white gap between the bottom of the control button bar and the bottom of the screen.

Are there any circumstances in which this could happen? There is nothing in the code that resizes the seekbar or button bar text. In fact, theres nothing in it that will resize any of the controls; the only resize is that of the loaded image to make sure it fits within the confines of the imageview. And at any rate, the size of that imageview doesn't change.

My xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frlayout"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iView"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:progress="1000"
    android:max="2000"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="#004D79"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/controlView">
    <Button
        android:text="Open File"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/ofbutton" />
    <Button
        android:text="Save File"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/sfbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes it could happen if you designed your layout wrong

Comment: try adding `scaleType` `centerInside` or other to your imageView

Comment: also try removing `android:adjustViewBounds`

Comment: Its odd because imageView is the only one that retains its size. Its the others that are resized (and just to make sure, I made marks on a piece of paper before and after image loading, and imageView is the same size, the others aren't)

Comment: OK, I've done what you suggested (the viewbounds and centerinside), and no change alas.